# Chrome Extentions: How can I get errors from console in active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want create support extention (only for my site) which will take errors from the console. So, how can I do this?

chrome.debugger gives access to some target, but how can I get all console on click event (or when error appears in the console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe it will be useful to someone:

1. manifest.json:

```js
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["your_site"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
```

---

2. in content_script.js inject another one script *(fore example: page_script.js)*:

```js
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('page_script.js');
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
    s.onload = function() {
        s.remove();
    };
```

we can comunicate with main js file of extension by **sendMessage()** method. [here is documentasion](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

---

3. in page_scripte.js we handle errors:

```js
let pageErr = [];
window.console.error = function () {
    pageErr.push((arguments.length === 1)?arguments[0]:Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
};
```

---

4. dispatch custom event in content_script.js when message from main js is sended, catch it in page_script.js, send another custom event from page_script.js to content_script.js and, at last, send data to main js

I think it's not best solution, but if anyone has any ideas, you are welcome=)

P.S.: I also tried to catch errors in content_script.js, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try window.ErrorEvent().it should work

Comment: yes. it's works, but it catch errors from my extention window. I have somthink like this: let log = [];
    window.addEventListener('error', (event) => {
        log.push(`${event.type}: ${event.message}`);
        console.log(log);
    });